# on button click, new window(internal frame) should open, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: java, swing

on button click, new window(internal frame) should open, what's wrong with my code?
can somebody explain the relationship between desktopane and internalframe and just
regular contentpane?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class tuna extends JFrame{

    private JButton button1;
    JDesktopPane desktop;
    JInternalFrame internalFrame;


    public tuna(){
        super("iLyrics");

        desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        add(desktop);

        button1 = new JButton("Open Internal Frame");
        add(button1);

        button1.addActionListener(

                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                              JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Internal Frame", true, true, true, true );
                              internalFrame.setBounds(110, 130, 105, 70);                 
                              desktop.add(internalFrame, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
                              //desktop.add(internalFrame);
                              internalFrame.setVisible(true);

                    }
                });
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: Did you set the size to the JInternalFrame or pack() it? The default size is 0x0.

Comment: You aren't specifying locations for either item in the layout, so doesn't that put the button on top of your desktop, covering it completely?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're adding the desktop and the button to the CENTER of the content pane, making the button *replace* the desktop pane, so you'll never see it.

```
    // put the desktop in the center
    desktop = new JDesktopPane(); 
    getContentPane().add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // but the button at the top
    button1 = new JButton("Open Internal Frame"); 
    getContentPane().add((button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: if this was the problem, don't forget to accept the answer (click the little check mark icon)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can add a frame to a pane. If you look at the hierarchy of swing containers. It would go Label -> Pane -> Frame. I think the problem with your code is when your doing

```
desktop.add(internalFrame);
```

I would change desktop to be a new JFrame

```
desktop = new JFrame();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html

This post talks about your relationship with top-level containers.

Comment: the OP is using JDesktop + JInternalFrame.  JDesktop allows you to create an MDI style interface, with JInternalFrames inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

add this code after you create jinternaframe:

```
internalFrame.setBounds(110, 130, 105, 70);                 
desktopPane.add(internalFrame, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
```

Comment: didn't help, i have a feeling it's a syntax error, but i simplified it to this, i just can't spot what's wrong..